# How do you clear all item drops in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you clear all item drops in Minecraft?
I want to have something activated by an Item landing on a golden pressure plate, but It can only be activated once. Is there any command block command that clears all entities?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're trying to clear all item drops in the world, you can run:

```
/kill @e[type=item]
```

which will kill all dropped items in the world. However, there are slightly better ways of doing this. Namely, only clear items within a radius of *x* blocks from the command block. This preserves drops elsewhere, but still clears the first item:

```
/kill @e[type=item,r=x]
```

---

Additionally, if you want to ensure that something can only be triggered once, place an input stabilizer on it:

[image: input stabilizer]

This device will "lock" the redstone state to ON, even after the item is removed. It cannot be re-triggered unless you manually break the redstone.

You can expand on this by only making it hold one pulse if so needed.

Comment: 1.13 syntax for second command: `/kill @e[type=item,distance=..x]`

Answer (score 0):

/remove items (radius) with the world edit plugin